# gps.getLasknowlocation returns null in emulator even after setting the location?

Tags: android, gps, android-emulator

The question is self explainatory. On debugging I see the location as null. Please suggest what further to triage.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

....

```
// if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
//                      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
//                              LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
//                              MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
//                              MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);



                if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

On debugging I see that gpsEnabled is alwaysreturned false. GPS is turned on on the emulator

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code, I'm assuming you're using GPSTracker or some derivation of it (which you shouldn't that code is broken).  If so, the gpsEnabled value just tells you whether its possible to use GPS, not whether its actually on and capable of giving you a value right now.

Comment: Still the question remain , why it is false. The emulator sure is capable of gps so it should be true rt? Unless there is some configuration in emulator

Answer (score 0):

You're using an emulator. It hasn't yet requested a location so you'll need to call `requestLocationUpdates()` or `requestSingleUpdate()` so that it stores a location for the device.

Another way to do this is to try clicking the menu on the right side of the emulator that looks like three dots and go to the Location section. If you put in a latitude and longitude in there and click "Send", does that work?

Comment: The issue is with the fact that you're using an emulator. Updated my answer

Comment: I tried using maps first just the way you thought , even the maps is waiting for the location .

Comment: Try clicking the menu on the right side of the emulator that looks like three dots and go to the Location section. If you put in a latitude and longitude in there and click "Send", does that work?

Comment: @UtsavGupta did clicking Send in the emulator options not work for you?

Comment: No, Josh it didnt, it changes the number in control panel, but i dont receive callback neither does google maps.  I have been searching there is a bug opened for this, could not find any yet.